# IAM Passrole not working (while assuming an IAM role)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have 2 IAM roles in same aws account

IAM_ROLE_1 : which has ec2 launch permission with s3 read permissions

IAM_ROLE_2 : which has only access to lamda with assume trust from IAM_ROLE_1

I am able to assume IAM_ROLE_2 from an instance which has IAM_ROLE_1 attached to it.

Now I want to read a s3 location (which IAM_ROLE_1 has access to) after assuming IAM_ROLE_2 .
My understanding is that I can do that with "iam:passrole"

Is this correct understanding ?

When I am adding below to IAM_ROLE_1 , and assuming IAM_ROLE_2 & accessing s3 bucket it still throwing access denied error.

```
{
        "Sid": "allowpassrole",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:PassRole",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::00000001:role/IAM_ROLE_2"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, but passing roles is [not cumulative](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html). Once you assume `IAM_ROLE_1`, and they you assume `IAM_ROLE_2` you give up your `IAM_ROLE_1` permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set of credentials is only associated with **one** IAM User or IAM Role at any time. Thus, to make a call using permissions associated with IAM Role 1, you would need to use credentials associated with that Role (not IAM Role 2).

To use IAM Role 1, simply create an Amazon S3 client object without specifying credentials. It will then use IAM Role 1 that is associated with the instance.

`iam:PassRole` is used to permit a service to assume a role on your behalf. For example, when launching the Amazon EC2 instance with the Role set to IAM Role 1, you would need permission to `PassRole` with IAM Role 1. Without this permission, you would not be able to launch the EC2 instance with that role.

PassRole is *not* used to pass permissions 'between' roles.